# Jenkins- Selenium Webdriver- Keeps loading in console for a long time more than an hour even after all tests are run

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I am using jenkins to run selenium webdriver scripts. The tests run successfully , and when i go to console , its shows loading icon  for a long time , even though the tests are run successfully. After a long time, it stops and displays success message. Can someone please help on this, as it is taking more time to see the results than testing the application manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you run you test using Chrome, try to login jenkins machine then kill chrome.exe and chromedriver.exe

```
taskkill /f /im chrome.exe
taskkill /f /im chromedriver.exe
```

Sometime webdriver is not able to terminate chrome.exe and chromedriver.exe then jenkins will hang forever

Comment: I am making run tests in firefox browser. you meant running jenkins on chrome browser or running selenium scripts on chrome browser? Please clarify